# mmap/cmap package does not affect on some fonts

Tags: font-encodings, cyrillic, ukrainian, font-map

The `cm-super` `\bfseries\sffamily` looks ugly, in my opinion. But, when I change fonts by strings

```
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fos}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}
```

text in `PDF` become unsearchable with this attributes (in `MWE`), even with `mmap/cmap` package.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = uk_UA
% !BIB program = bibtex8


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion, tracking=true, kerning=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{mmap}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\title{\bfseries\sffamily ЗАГОЛОВОК}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fos}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b} 
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Теоретичне підґрунтя}

У цій роботі вивчається інтерференційна картина, що виникає при освітленні єдиним світловим пучком товстої плоскопаралельної скляної пластини, тобто використовується \emph{метод поділу амплітуди}. В цьому випадку світлові промені, що інтерферують формуються при відбиванні світла від граней пластини.

\end{document}
```

It is possible to solve this with `pdflatex.exe` (not `lua-` or `xelatex`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sumatra has no problems with your example, but the adobe reader doesn't copy&paste. mmap is for math resources, cmap doesn't work with fonts which use virtual fonts. Try glyphtounicode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion, tracking=true, kerning=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{misccorr}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{fos}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}

\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1

\begin{document}
\sffamily вивчається 
\end{document}
```